# Соглашение по именованию переменных с++

Tags: c++

Есть какое-либо соглашение/стандарт, следуя которому стоит называть свои переменные/функции/ классы в с+, как например в [с#](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/naming-guidelines)?

Comment: Есть, но не все с ними согласны.

Comment: Есть *стили* программирования. Причем самые разнообразные. Например - https://google.github.io/styleguide/cppguide.html

Comment: большими буквами: имена-макросы. Первые два подчёркивания - для компиляторов. Вот и всё..

Comment: Нет, нету. Не считая запрета на определенные имена (`__` в любом месте, `_[A-Z]` в начале, и плюс, если имя в глобальном пространстве имен, `_` в начале).

Comment: помню в древности писали m_ (мембер) потом p(point) b(bool) в итоге получалось m_pbVar - понятно было, что это член данных указатель на бул.. но счас в основном просто прочерк вначале ставят _var (по крайней мере я)